# Remove Version Number of js files retrieved via Nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I'm wondering if there is a way to have nuget or part of mvc4 strip the version number from js files like jquery.

I'm wondering this for instance if I have nuget update jquery.  It would be nice if I didn't have worry about the version numbers scattered in my views.

I'm aware that I can do a find/replace on the filename, but would prefer it if there wasn't a version number at all.  I do however want to retain the ability to run the `update-package jQuery` and have it function.

Comment: Isn't the real problem "the version numbers scattered in my views"? Have a single EverythingInMyHeader-file and include that everywhere.

Comment: jQuery may have been a bad example.  jQuery UI might have been better.  It would be rather silly to download on EVERY page when I only need the calendar/tabs/according on a few pages.  I guess that's the situation that I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bundling for that. The idea is then use the bundle and configure it just once in a file.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389545/ASP-NET-MVC4-Bundling-and-Minification